# SAML SSO in cakephp application

Tags: cakephp, authentication, saml

I have a cakephp application which needs users to be authenticated via SAML Sign Sign on. For this, I have followed the link "https://github.com/zl4bv/CakePHP-simpleSAMLphp-Plugin".

According to its documentation, I have downloaded fresh copies of cakephp and simpleSAMLphp. Now, I have a cakephp folder and simpleSAMLphp folder in my workspace. I have imstalled simpleSAMLphp as described in link "https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/". 
I followed these steps:
(1) I configured simpleSAML in apache congiguration as below:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName service.local-saml.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/simplesamlphp/www/

       <Directory "/var/www/simplesamlphp/www/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(2) Now, in simplesamlphp application folder, I changed values for 'auth.adminpassword',  'secretsalt', 'technicalcontact_name', 'technicalcontact_email' in **/config/config.php** file.

(3) I used SAML:sp module which is by default enabled.

(4) First, I started with SAML as a Identity Provider.

(5) I enabled 'enable.saml20-idp' => true, in **/config/config.php** file.

(6) Created a ssl self-signed certificate by using command on terminal

```
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -days 3652 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/simplesamlphp.crt -keyout /etc/ssl/certs/simplesamlphp.pem
```

(7) Moved the above certificates to **simplesamlphp/cert**.
(8) Added private key and certificate to **config/authsources.php**

```
'default-sp' => array(
        'saml:SP',
            'privatekey' => 'simplesamlphp.pem',
            'certificate' => 'simplesamlphp.crt',

    )
```

(9) Added private key and certicates to "**metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php**" file also.

(10) Changed the metadata in "**metadata/saml20-sp-remote.php**"

```
$metadata['http://service.local-saml.com'] = array(
        'AssertionConsumerService' => 'http://service.local-saml.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
        'SingleLogoutService' => 'http://service.local-saml.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp',
    );
```

(11) I added the metadata on link "https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?AuthState=_36266db92ac88d2d66ae8ede39dd1264a39243f08e%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fopenidp.feide.no%2Fsimplesaml%2Fmodule.php%2Fcore%2Fas_login.php%3FAuthId%3Dopenidp-ldap%26ReturnTo%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fopenidp.feide.no%252Fsimplesaml%252Fmodule.php%252Fmetaedit%252Findex.php".

(12) I typed the url "http://service.local-saml.com/simplesaml" on browser and it is working correctly. I tried to login with default-sp option and it is working correctly.

Now, I want to use this simplesamlphp with my cakephp application. 
(13) For this, as mentioned in "https://github.com/zl4bv/CakePHP-simpleSAMLphp-Plugin", I put the saml folder in /app/plugin folder of Cakephp

(14) I added lines on core.php and bootstrap.php files.

(15) I made a usersController and made same as given in example files of the link.

(16) I added folllowing

```
'sp1' => array(
            'saml:SP',
            'privatekey' => 'simplesamlphp.pem',
            'certificate' => 'simplesamlphp.crt',
            'entityID' => 'http://localhost/cakephp1',
    ),
```

in config/authsources.php of simplesamlphp.

(17) I added metadata in metadata/saml20-sp-remote.php

```
$metadata['http://localhost/cakephp'] = array(
        'AssertionConsumerService' => 'http://localhost/cakephp',
        'SingleLogoutService' => 'http://localhost/cakephp',
);
```

When I typed **localhost/cakephp** on browser, the link redirected to "https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php", user, enters his username and password, but "**State information lost**" error is displaying at "**http://service.local-saml.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/sp1**" and user is not returned to "**localhost/cakephp**". I want user to be returned to cakephp url when user enters login credentials.

Please help me where I am wrong and what something I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that cakephp and simpleSAMLphp have sessions conflicts. One poasible solution is to install memcache and use memcache has session handler for simpleSAMLphp.
https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-maintenance#section_2_1

But there are more ways, check:
https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/simplesamlphp-nostate

Comment: Not working.  My simple purpose is: I have a application "http://localhost/cakephp". I want users to be redirected to "https://openidp.feide.no" when they are not logged in, and after entering login credentials, they are not redirected to my site "http://localhost/cakephp". They are redirected to "http://service.local-saml.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/sp1" with error message "State Information Lost". My first question is "Why user came to url 'http://service.local-saml.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/sp1', instead of my site url? What wrong in above steps?

Comment: My simple requirement is : I want to use simplesamlphp as a Library instead of application. Please suggest me steps to follow for this

Comment: Maybe the metadata that you registered at feide already matches other entity, try change the domain and register again the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also set cookie domain in php.ini?

```
session.cookie_domain = ".feide.no"
```

NB! If you use PHP sessions, you will also have to make sure that your application uses the same domain when it sets the cookie. Read [this source](https://code.google.com/p/simplesamlphp/wiki/LostState) for more information. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easy way to include simplesamlphp in cakephp without this plugin

1- add your configured and working simplesamlphp in app/Lib folder
2 - in your controller make your custom method in my case i made auth()

```
    function auth()
{
    $this->layout='ajax';
    $this->autoRender=false;
         require_once(APP . 'Lib/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php');

SimpleSAML_Logger::info('SAML2.0 - IdP.SSOService: Accessing SAML 2.0 IdP endpoint SSOService');

$metadata = SimpleSAML_Metadata_MetaDataStorageHandler::getMetadataHandler();
$idpEntityId = $metadata->getMetaDataCurrentEntityID('saml20-idp-hosted');
$idp = SimpleSAML_IdP::getById('saml2:' . $idpEntityId);
sspmod_saml_IdP_SAML2::receiveAuthnRequest($idp);
assert('FALSE');

    }
```

instead of hitting url of simplesamlphp 
like this
http://yoursimplesamlphpurl.com/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?spentityid=spname

Use this url of your cakephp application 
http://your-cakeappurl.com/CakeControllername/auth?spentityid=spname

Comment: Thanks Fahad for reply. I will try with this method, and if successfully works, I will accept it as answer